# Idle power consumption of J4125 vs N5105

Tags: cpu, power

I'm looking to build a router (and being able to have a couple of lightweight VMs would be useful to), and came across a number of x86 router boxes from Aliexpress for around US$250 each.

Both CPU's claim a 10 watt TDP, but while the J4125 uses a 14nm process, the N5105 uses a 10nm process.  Of-course the N5105 is significantly faster.   The kicker though is [this video](https://youtu.be/rUuaAPG0PxU?t=1006) where "Patrick from STH" claims that the power consumption is significantly higher on the N5105 board (4.5 watt idle (10w under load) for J4125 vs 10-12 watt idle up to 24 watts for the N5105).     There is another review of the J4125 by the same person [here](https://www.servethehome.com/topton-intel-j4125-4x-i225-fanless-virtualized-firewall-appliance-review-pfsense-opnsense-proxmox-ve/).

What are the likely explanations for the substantial difference in power consumption?

Comment: You are comparing power usage of two different systems not just CPU’s. Things like RAM and SSD’s are going to use power. Then there are potential differences in the motherboards themselves. If anything it suggests that the J4125 is not being used to full potential, who knows what the firmware on the board is doing. Also there are factors in the OS and we don’t know if they were set up to use the same power profile. Lastly, if they use different PSU’s and power draw is measured from the wall then differing efficiencies will affect the results

Comment: In other words, it’s probably a combination of things but it looks like one system is optimised for low power consumption and the other is trying to eek out more performance from the form factor

Comment: @jamesp I think that's part of the story story.  After reading other online forums (can't find them anymore) I still understand the actual CPU is actually a lot more more power hungry, and I think there are issues with CSTATES as well.  (Apparently though the PSU's they ship with are quite inefficient which does explain 3-6 watts so you are right there).

Comment: Even disregarding the fact that they are completely different systems rather than just different CPU's, in order for it to be a fair test someone would need to check the settings in Windows and the UEFI to make sure things are equivalent. For instance, the difference between High Performance and Balanced power modes in Windows alone can be substantial. Plus the power states etc. can often be tweaked in the UEFI

Comment: @JamesP Windows has nothing to do with this.  The systems are using Linux.  The same application is using more power.  This seems to be true regardless of motherboard, RAM or disk.

Comment: I admit I got mixed up mentioning Windows as I was thinking about mini PC's in general rather than something for a specific use case like this kind of device.  But my point about the specific type/configuration of OS being a factor for power consumption is still correct. For instance, an N5105 system showing significantly higher power consumption (more than double) idling in Windows compared to Ubuntu: https://www.cnx-software.com/2022/02/23/aerofara-aero-2-pro-review-celeron-n5105-mini-pc-windows-11-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @jamesp Useful power comments in that link - thank you!